# ImageTransfer using bluetooth on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bluetooth

I am trying to use the Open Source project 
https://github.com/unixpickle/ImageTransfer 
to send and receive image via bluetooth on iOS/Xcode. I downloaded the project as is from github, built on xcode (xcode 6.1) and then tried running it on two iphone 5c (both using ios 8.0)
When I start the app on both the iphones, I get the message "Looking for other iphone or ipod touch devices).
However this is followed by a blank list (in other words "choose an ipad, iphone or ipod touch window" is empty whereas I was expecting it to list the other iphone)
The code that is being used for detection is simple (in the file ImageTransferViewController.m)

```
self.mPicker = [[[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
mPicker.delegate = self;
//mPicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
[mPicker show];
```

This seems to be the standard way of using the GameKit to detect other bluetooth devices.
I do understand that GKPeerPickerController has been deprecated since ios 7.0
Could this be the reason for the empty bluetooth device detection ? Is there a port of this project for ios8.0 or later ? Is there a work around (to using this older code base (I think it was written for iOS 5.0 or earlier) on a newer iOS (8.1)) ? Xcode 6.1 doesn't even seem to have an option to make the deployment target as 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just following up on this - I still haven't figured out what the underlying issues are, but I made the following observations

- If I run the above open source app on an IOS 7 device (as opposed to an IOS 8 device) it works fine
- For IOS 8 devices if I modify the above app and remove the peer discovery code from the initialization functions of the app to some other function (which gets called say, when a button is pushed), the peer discovery happens properly.

So for now I seem to have a workaround - either (a) use a device running ios 7 or even older (as opposed to ios8) Even thought the GameKit API was deprecated in IOS7, it still seems to work on IOS7 devices. Or (b) If running the app on an IOS8 device, remove the peer discovery code from the app initialization functions and move it somewhere else (preferably make it an IBAction). In other words it works on IOS8 devices but not necessarily as expected. 
 Best is to stop using the GameKit framework and migrate to the multi peer connectivity framework at the earliest